# How to capture a dynamic ID from a URL whose request is failing in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

This is in addition to the question already asked:

Please refer the image displayed on clicking the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0lSD.png

Questions:

1. Is it possible to extract the highlighted values - Blazor ID and Timestamp in JMeter even when the response fails? (Since these values are unique, dynamic and change for each session - it fails on rerunning them)
2. Is it possible to create/record > amend > run JMeter scripts when we have such dynamic and unique values involved?

I have tried to capture the Blazor ID through Regular Expressions.
But JMeter is not able to capture it from URL (Tried it with all options in JMeter - URL, Body, Headers, Response etc).
Is this because the request is failing? Please have a look at the SS and let me know if anything has to be corrected from my end.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK1SF.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ZNm.png

Comment: Could you please add the origin of the URL, because you are trying to fetch something from the request method, which must be originating at the beginning or somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Thank you. The Regular expression worked fine for ID. The ID is generated for each session and they are not available anywhere before it appears in the first request. How can I pull the value from from URL for the first time even before the request is generated in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Regex Expression need to be change,

`for id` use `id=([^&]*)`

and `for time`  use `&_=([^&]*)`

[image]

[image]

[image]